# vim: .vimrc doesn't load properly with python files

Tags: python, vim

Everytime I load a **.py** file, my plugins takes long to load and my `vimrc` seem to not load properly and shows weird behaviour. For example if I check my tabstop length with `:set tabstop` it says tabstop=2 as it should but when I insert one it have a length of 4.

If I reload the vimrc with `:source $MYVIM` it works fine, but i have to reload it everytime I open a .py file with a fresh vim instance

This behaviour startet after recompiling vim with python support.

**Here my `vim --version :`**

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  3 2014 04:36:01)
included patches: 1-86
Compiled by Arch Linux
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
-clientserver    -hangul_input    -netbeans_intg   +title
-clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   +perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3/dyn     +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            -ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -march=x86-64 

-mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE 

-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE  -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -lncurses -lelf    -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl   -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE -Wl,-O1,--sort-common,--as-needed,-z,relro -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/perl5/core_perl/CORE -lperl -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc
```

Comment: I suspect compiling vim with python may be causing problems with one of your plugins (perhaps because it was created to use a different version of python or whatever reason). Try using the `vim -N -u NONE something.py` to help diagnose the problem with a clean instance of vim. You can also use `--noplugin`.

Comment: Post your vimrc? Whats the value of softtabstop? Are you actually inserting tabs or spaces?

Comment: `~/.vimrc` is only executed once, at startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If loading a Python file within an existing vim session overrides settings from your .vimrc, that's almost certainly because you have an autocommand triggered to run on FileType detection. For instance, I have this in my .vimrc:

```
au FileType python set shiftwidth=2
```

which resets the soft tab value to 2 spaces when I open a Python file.

You might have something similar either in your .vimrc, or even in a file in your vim/ftplugin directory.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have compiled Vim with Python and with Python3. I have seen warnings about this elsewhere. Perhaps you should reinstall Vim with either Python or Python 3 but not both.